# Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, overflow

I copied a multidimensional array from java, but i am having some problems to free the memory after using it.

what i did is:

```
jfieldID h_valID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, h_cls, "val", "[[I");
jobjectArray h_val_obj = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, h, h_valID);
int h_val_local[xdim][ydim];
for(i=0; i<xdim; i++)
{
    h_val_one_dim = (jintArray) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, h_val_obj, i);
    h_val_elem = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, h_val_one_dim, 0);
    for(j=0; j<ydim; j++)
    {
        h_val_local[i][j] = h_val_elem[j];
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, h_val_one_dim, h_val_elem, 0);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, h_val_one_dim);
}
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, h_val_obj);
```

I have 4 more arrays on that method, all on the parameters, i'm getting the pointer then releasing after using it.

```
int *x = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env,x_p,0);
int *y = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env,y_p,0);
int *v = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env,v_p,0);
int *w = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env,w_p,0);
```

...

```
(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, x_p, x, 0);
(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, y_p, y, 0);
(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, v_p, v, 0);
(*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, w_p, w, 0);
```

For bigger files, i'm getting overflow on the reference table. What i'm forgetting to free or how do i fix this?

Log:

> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598): ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598): Last 10 entries in JNI pinned array reference table:
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1014: 0x46109fe8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1015: 0x4610a008 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1016: 0x46109fa8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1017: 0x46109fc8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1018: 0x46109fe8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1019: 0x4610a008 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1020: 0x46109fa8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1021: 0x46109fc8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1022: 0x46109fe8 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1023: 0x4610a008 cls=[I (24 bytes)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598): JNI pinned array reference table summary (1024 entries):
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598):  1024 of [I 24B (4 unique)
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: W/dalvikvm(23598): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 96 bytes
>
> 10-02 14:18:58.885: E/dalvikvm(23598): Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what i was doing wrong, better, what i forgot to do. I have another return point in the code, but i forgot to release the arrays before returning in that case, i was only releasing it at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the JNI implementation to me. One obvious workaround is to use a one-dimensional array instead. The array is not jagged on Java side, it seems, so it would be pretty straightforward to convert back and forth. The index of the element `(i,j)` in the 1D array would be `i*xdim + j`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i found out that the problem was not in the part that i posted above.